# Can I make @OnApplicationStart not run on tests?

Tags: java, testing, junit, playframework

I just found out that classes annotated with @OnApplicationStart run when I run jUnit tests (via IntelliJ).

Can I disable this? I have some logic that is only relevant on real application startup, but not in tests.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes you can check test mode in your doJob method for that

```
@Override
public void doJob() throws Exception {
    if (!Play.runingInTestMode()) {
        // Do your stuff
    }
}
```